# Share code between asset and view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I have a set of about 40 lines of code that I need to use in both a .js.coffee asset file and a .js.erb file in the view. It has setup code for an object that is used when I load existing objects on the page (code in the asset file) and when I dynamically create a new object (code in the view).

It seems I cannot use a partial in an asset file because those are static. I tried to make a function in the asset for for the code and call it in the view but the view file couldn't find the function. (Is this because Coffeescript wraps all their code in an anonymous function?) Currently, I have the code duplicated on both files, but it's WET and smelly and generally unpleasant to be around.

**Code from asset**

```
setUpEvent = (start, end, $event) ->
    startIdx = getHeaderIndex start
    $event.addClass "cell-#{startIdx}"

    endIdx = getHeaderIndex end
    $event.width((endIdx - startIdx) * 94)

    draggableOptions =
        revert: 'invalid'
        helper: 'clone'  # needed to work with grid
        grid: [101, 101]
        start: (e, ui) ->
            # hide so only helper clone is visible
            $(this).css 'visibility', 'hidden'
            ui.helper.addClass 'dragging dragged-event'
        stop: (e, ui) ->
            $(this).css 'visibility', 'visible'
            ui.helper.removeClass 'dragging dragged-event'

    resizableOptions =
        containment: 'parent'
        grid: [100, 0]
        handles: 'e, w'
        minWidth: 94
        stop: (e, ui) ->
            eventId = ui.element.data 'id'
            startColumn = Math.floor(ui.position.left / 100)
            endColumn = Math.ceil((ui.position.left + ui.size.width) / 100)
            data =
                start: getColumnDate startColumn
                end: getColumnDate endColumn
            updateEvent ui.element.data('id'), data

    $event
        .draggable(draggableOptions)
        .resizable(resizableOptions)
```

**How can I share code between an asset and a view?**

Answer (score 0):

Your function will run regardless of whether it's visible outside the file. Just have it access whatever DOM elements it needs, and make sure it's wrapped in a `$(document).ready)` callback.

Comment: Will it be visible outside the file? I want to use it in a view file, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's backwards. What I'm telling you is that the JavaScript will run, and find your view. Make sure your view outputs what the JavaScript expects to see. You shouldn't be directly invoking JavaScript from your views.

Comment: It's a javascript view (.js.erb). I'm dynamically creating an event using Ajax so there's no page reload.

Answer (score 0):

To access the Coffeescript function outside of the file, I had to make the function global by prefixing it with @ (i.e. `@setUpEvent`). This only works when the function is defined in the top-level because [what @ really does is bind the variable to `this`](http://coffeescript.org/#operators).